# Representing a DB schema in JSON

Tags: json, hive

Let's say I have two tables in my database, `employee` and `car` defined thusly.

employee:

```
+--------------+------------+
|   col_name   | data_type  | 
+--------------+------------+
| eid          | int        |
| name         | string     |
| salary       | int        |
| destination  | string     |
+--------------+------------+
```

car:

```
+------------+----------------+
|  col_name  |   data_type    |
+------------+----------------+
| cid        | int            |
| name       | string         |
| model      | string         |
| cylinders  | int            |
| price      | int            |
+------------+----------------+
```

I would like to export this schema to a JSON object so that I can populate an HTML dropdown menu based on the table - for instance, the `table` menu would have `employee` and `car`. Selecting `employee` would populate another dropdown with the column names and types corresponding to that table.

Given this use case, would the optimal json representation of the database be this?

```
{
    "employee": {
        "salary": "int", 
        "destination": "string", 
        "eid": "int", 
        "name": "string"
    }, 
    "car": {
        "price": "int", 
        "model": "string", 
        "cylinders": "int", 
        "name": "string", 
        "cid": "int"
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Or would this be more appropriate?

```
{
    "employee": [
        {
            "type": "int", 
            "colname": "eid"
        }, 
        {
            "type": "string", 
            "colname": "name"
        }, 
        {
            "type": "int", 
            "colname": "salary"
        }, 
        {
            "type": "string", 
            "colname": "destination"
        }
    ], 
    "car": [
        {
            "type": "int", 
            "colname": "cid"
        }, 
        {
            "type": "string", 
            "colname": "name"
        }, 
        {
            "type": "string", 
            "colname": "model"
        }, 
        {
            "type": "int", 
            "colname": "cylinders"
        }, 
        {
            "type": "int", 
            "colname": "price"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question, just if the example json would be the optimal representation? I think it is an appropriate representation given the use case you described.

Comment: Thanks @martink - I've added another JSON structure - given a choice, which would be most appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, all your data is stored in objects. Assuming the structure is stored in a var `mytables`, you can get the names with `Object.keys(mytables)`, which returns `['employee', 'car']`. Equivalent for the columns inside: `Object.keys(mytables['employee'].cols)` returns `['salary','destination','eid','name']`.

In the second example I would suggest to also store the tables in an array as the columns, like

```
[name: 'employee', 
 cols: [ {
           "type": "int", 
           "colname": "cid"
         }, ...]
```

Then you can easily iterate over the arrays and get the names by accessing `mytables[i].name`

```
for (t in tables){
  console.log(tables[t].name);
  for (c in tables[t].cols)
    console.log(" - ",tables[t].cols[c].colname, ": ", tables[t].cols[c].type);
}
```